# What is a best way in Ubuntu to create password protected text files?

Tags: libreoffice, text-editor

I need to send people formatted text files, like odt or doc.

But I want to protect these files from editing. Not to give them an easy way to use these files as templates. Near to all of the people I send files to, use Windows.

What is the easiest and safest way to do it in Ubuntu?

Comment: Unfortunately the only real way to do this is encryption so they have to have codes to decrypt or access the files inside of an encrypted file container.  The tricky part is that you're going from Ubuntu to Windows, and OpenOffice/LibreOffice likely to Microsoft Office, and password protection isn't the same on those...

Comment: I do not ask for a really secure thing, like encryption. They should be able to read files, so they can retype them, or print, OCR, etc. Just not to let easy copy paste.

Comment: That's document level security controls, and that's a Microsoft thing, IIRC.  I don't believe LibreOffice/OpenOffice have that level of 'edit' controls... however if you're really concerned about that, save them as PDFs before distributing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it using Libre Office Writer.

When I save a file, I check "Save with password".

[image]

Then click "Save", "More options"  and check "Open file read only" there.

[image]

I set a password to allow editing.

And I **do not** set an encryption password.

After this setting Microsoft Office does not let to edit the file at all, and LibreOffice askes for a password at first attempt to edit.

I saved files in MSO `.doc` format.